# Hybris Solr Sort configuration

Tags: java, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Because I don't found an answer neither on the web nor on the Hybris guide, I ask this question here.

In Solr schema.xml I have a dynamicField with pattern name *_sortabletext of type sortabletext.

In the solr.impex for table SolrIndexedProperty  is defined the row follows:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true];name[unique=true];type(code);sortableType(code);currency[default=false];localized[default=false];multiValue[default=false];useForSpellchecking[default=false];useForAutocomplete[default=false];fieldValueProvider;valueProviderParameter;ftsPhraseQuery[default=false];ftsPhraseQueryBoost;ftsQuery[default=false];ftsQueryBoost;ftsFuzzyQuery[default=false];ftsFuzzyQueryBoost;ftsWildcardQuery[default=false];ftsWildcardQueryType(code)[default=POSTFIX];ftsWildcardQueryBoost;ftsWildcardQueryMinTermLength;$classAttributeAssignment
;$solrIndexedType; name;text;sortabletext;;true;;true;true;springELValueProvider;getName(#lang);true;100;true;600;;25;;;50;3
```

What is the purpose of indicating that sortbletext for the sortableType(code) column in this table?

Answer (score 0):

It defines on which way this property could be sorted. 'sortabletext' means you can sort the result alphanumeric.

You could also sort depending on int values, etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, there's something that isn't clear to me. What is the utility of the fieldType sortabletext and of the dynamicField * _sortabletext?
I wonder why when I run the query I see sort=name_sortabletext_en_sortabletext

Comment: The Parameter is a combination of two parts. 'sortabletext' the Type and 'sortabletext_en' which is a solr property in your Server. Hybris creates for every language a solr 'sortabletext_xx' field. Because you want to sort your results depending on the language. Go in your solr server. There you will see the field

Comment: So, if I understand correctly if I sort the results according to the property name, it will add to the query sort=name_sortable_en_sortabletext.
So if the property would be called desc what will be added to the query will be sort=desc_sortable_en_sortabletext.
Did I get it right?